# Approve or Flag commented questions that need improvement

Tags: discussion, questions, review

Sometimes there is a question from a new user in my review queue that needs to be improved by the OP.  When I view it in my review queue, someone else has already done a good job leaving a comment to the OP regarding how they can improve their question.  Is it appropriate to approve the question, or is it appropriate to flag it for removal?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say there's no general advice here. I often sit in the very same situation, additionally with the "Delete" option. If it's a new user's first question, and just a few hours old – I'd prefer they'd get a real chance to fix it up; their first question deleted within minutes just scares them away. Which there was a possibility to set a reminder: "Re-visit this in xx days"...

So basically, I've set myself the following set of rules:

- First question of new user:

  - no comment: leave a comment, *flag* if needed (a flag doesn't delete, but gives the chance someone else checks it again later)
  - has "fresh" comment: *flag* as above; "fresh" means not older than 1..2 days
  - has "settled" comment: *flag* and, if the link is there, mark for deletion. User had his chance and didn't take it – so either he doesn't care or even not return at all. Still has the chance to improve it and get it re-opened.
- Question of experienced user: Here I tend to hit "delete" faster – "freshman's bonus" gone :)

In general: Flagging a post doesn't "destroy" it – it simply brings it to attention (either pushing it to the review queue, or additionally popping up in the moderators' console – depending on how you've flagged it). So I'd say: When in doubt, flag it – so someone else can cross-check.